# pysimplegui print stack trace to console

Tags: python, stack-trace, pysimplegui

I'm trying my hand at pysimplegui to build my first UI. However, I keep getting an error but in a flash a stack trace appears before the screen, the program ends and unable to read it. Is there anyway to print the stack trace from pysimplegui to the console in PyCharm to use as a way of debugging?

Had a look at the docs but sadly nothing I can see and the docs are not as simple as the library.

Cheers

Comment: run code manually in `console`/`terminal`/`cmd.exe`  - `python script.py` - to get error message in `console`/`terminal`/`cmd.exe`

Comment: I tried that but did not work but instead ran it in pdb and it worked, thanks for helping me get there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to get it worked, I ran it in debug mode in the command line and I now see the issue

Comment: That's the right approach.... open a command.exe window, or terminal window, then launch your program from there.  If you double-click a .py file, then it'll close when an error happens (as you found out the hard way).